# How to wall mount a rack when studs don't line up

Tags: rack, rackmount

This is my first time mounting a server rack and I'd like some advice. The rack is for my home and will be a 10U wall mount for a patch panel, switch, and a few shelves for UPS and modem/satellite hardware. I might add a server or two in the future, but nothing right now. The studs in the wall are 20" on center (Don't ask). What is the best way for me to mount the rack to this wall?

I'm going to assume that just having one side of the rack in a stud and the other side mounted to plywood would be a bad idea. The only option I can come up with is to horizontally attach two 2x4s to the studs and then mount the server rack to the new 2x4s. I'm sure this problem has been solved before, but I can't seem to find where. Hopefully you guys can either confirm my plan or tell me a better way to do it. Thanks!

Edit: Sorry this is off topic. I'll post in the Super User section for things like this in the future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either of your solutions (plywood or horizontal 2x4s) will work fine. If you do plywood, just mount a large enough piece to the wall that the entire rack can hang off of it, not just one side.

Don't over-think things. As long as the rack has adequate support, it'll be fine.